# In Mario Kart Wii, how to jump over the canyon gap in Mushroom Gorge?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

If going to YouTube and search for ["Mushroom Gorge no-glitch"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0SRy1A0Igw) there will be many world record runs that, right before the finish line, the players will jump over the canyon gap.  They usually use Funky Kong and the Flame Runner bike.

I tried that but simply can't  jump over though.  Using a Mushroom boost, Funky Kong always fall a little and not able to catch the road, but hit the side of the mountain instead and fall off.  I also tried Wheelie first, and then use the Mushroom boost, and the same thing happened.

Is there a way to do it?  Such as Mushroom over some bump, and then also perform a trick for the jump, so that the jump is higher?  -- How is that done?

Comment: Erm... I believe we could use a spell check in here... Perhaps the second paragraph... The name of a certain character is inconveniently misspelled :P

Comment: @Grace Note Since I don't have editing privileges, could you edit in the following link to his "Mushroom Gorge no-glitch" text:? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0SRy1A0Igw

Comment: Been ages since I did it, so commenting rather than answering. It's mostly one of those things where practice makes perfect -- keep trying and you'll get it eventually. Things like this require very tight timing and positioning, and perhaps the positioning in the video linked is particularly hard for this trick -- and thus a little faster. I remember being much closer to the left when pulling this off, so I suggest trying it that way first.

Answer (score 2):

From the video, it looks like the player does a trick off the final mushroom in the cave to get a boost, does a wheelie, then, just before he hits the grass, uses a mushroom boost. As he's in the air over the canyon, he steers to the left.

Keep trying!  You'll get it.

Answer (score -1):

Right after you mushroom at the grasses edge you need to hop to get more air and there is no wheelie required.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has downvotes, I think it's correct, and adds more to the currently higher-point answer. I think the player _does_ do a hop at the edge.